# Nginx configuration not proxying to keycloak server

Tags: nginx, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have setup a Keycloak server on public cloud on CentOs which is running on `8080` port which I am able to access from my browser.

I have setup `Nginx` reverse proxy with the below configuration. When I hit the URL, I am seeing a `notification message` on the screen

[image]

Where am I going wrong.

I am getting below error from `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2021/05/13 12:00:45 [crit] 15247#0: *84 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/3/03/0000000033" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 106.51.240.105, server: , request: "GET /auth/resources/icg6b/common/keycloak/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/resources/icg6b/common/keycloak/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js", host: "161.35.23.133"
2021/05/13 12:00:45 [crit] 15247#0: *87 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/4/03/0000000034" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 106.51.240.105, server: , request: "GET /auth/resources/icg6b/common/keycloak/lib/ui-ace/min/ace.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/resources/icg6b/common/keycloak/lib/ui-ace/min/ace.js", host: "161.35.23.133"
2021/05/13 12:00:46 [crit] 15247#0: *89 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/5/03/0000000035" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 106.51.240.105, server: , request: "GET /auth/resources/icg6b/admin/keycloak/js/app.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/resources/icg6b/admin/keycloak/js/app.js", host: "161.35.23.133"
2021/05/13 12:00:46 [crit] 15247#0: *91 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/6/03/0000000036" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 106.51.240.105, server: , request: "GET /auth/resources/icg6b/admin/keycloak/js/controllers/clients.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/resources/icg6b/admin/keycloak/js/controllers/clients.js", host: "161.35.23.133"
```

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        # To forward the original client's IP address
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # to forward the  original protocol (HTTP or HTTPS)
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # to forward the original host requested by the client

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
...
```

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: I guess keycloak isn't letting you load those files, but neither doing the redirection properly. Make sure the proxy address forwarding is enabled for your keycloak instance, too. Here's a set up article I wrote last year, you might find it useful: https://making.quienconduce.com/

Comment: This worked. I added the prosy address forwarding and it started working.